# FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

I am  deploying a web application and getting following exception when try to deploy through tomcat 9.

**I am getting below exception in tomcat while deployment  FAIL - Application at context path [/webCenter-EN-Entitlement] could not be started FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@299321e2]]**

In Tomcat Log files found following exception. Please help with any solution. Your help is appreciated in advance.

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@2d1dee39]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4830)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4966)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [H:\XXXXXX] is not valid
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:751)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:708)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 41 more
```

Comment: No solution yet. Somebody please  advice.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved. Folder which contains my web application was not have necessary permission to the account which was used to Run Tomcat Service.